# GFCI trips when lights go on

Tags: wiring, gfci

I have this setup (see attached photo, and sorry for my poor drawing skills) and whenever I screw in the light bulb (or flip the switch with the light bulb in), the GFCI trips. Without the bulbs, no tripping.
What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks very much in advance!

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: Forgot to mention that N means that's a white wire and L means black. I did check with a voltage detector and black is hot, white is not.

Comment: The two travelers between a pair of three-ways must always be accompanied by a third conductor carrying the corresponding current in the other direction. - If you are able to replace this cable then you could power the lights from the unprotected mains instead of from the GFCI. If you cannot run a #/3wG between the three-ways then you will need to use smart switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Nope, you can't go in a loop like that...

You have power going in a big circle.  Power flows from "J-box", to the GFCI device, off its load to the outlet, then through both 3-way switches back to "J-box" and on to the light.  Neutral does not flow back the reverse route.  That's a big big problem, because the currents in each cable are not equal, which means you're inducing a lot of EMFs, getting eddy current heating, and other badnesses.  You need to fix that, separately from the GFCI problem.

Generally, non-UK wiring is done in a physical "tree" topology.  Wiring may zig up and back several branches, but if you stuck a clamp ammeter around all the wires in a cable together, it will always say 0 since they cancel each other out with equal flows.  Yours does not do that.

There should be /3 cable between the two 3-way switches.

The GFCI is a separate issue.  You must always power things symmetrically, but with a GFCI it's actually going to cause a trip. In this case the light gets its "hot" off the GFCI `LOAD` terminals, but gets its neutral direct from source.  That means the hot current leaving the GFCI is not matched by an equal amount of neutral current returning, exactly what they are made to detect.

### Smart switch option 1: radio/wireless/powerline coding

This works for smart switches which **do not** need a communication wire.

You will need a "master" smart switch and matching remote, or at least, units designed to work in the same home-automation system.  The remote must only take always-hot and neutral, and relies on radio or powerline comms to talk to the master.

Fit the "master" in the right 3-way position, connecting its always-hot, neutral and switched-hot to the wireds readily available here.

On the left 3-way, the wire heading north from COM, remove it.  Boom, it's gone.  Loop broken.

The two wires between the 3-ways are redesignated for always-hot and neutral and carry power to the remote switch.   If the remote is battery operated, you don't need this pair at all.

### Smart switch option 2: communication wire

Again a master and remote designed to work with each other.  But the search for a suitable unit will be harder.

First, on these, you must consult with the manufacturer and ask them if the switches can be on two different *services*.   Say it just like that,  not subpanel, different *service*.   If they want more, tell them they will be on opposite sides of a GFCI.  And get the manufacturer's advice.  To be clear, when I say "manufacturer" I do not mean the former landscaper former meth-head who now works in the paint department at Lowes and you caught coming back from the bathroom.  Best advice: don't buy anything like this at a big box, buy from a local electrical distributor.  Best advice: don't buy anything from a big-box.

In this case, you hook up the master in the right 3-way position as before; grabbing available hot, neutral and switched-hot.

On the left switch, you are already bringing down always-hot from the passthrough... Grab neutral there as well.  Note that this switch will be powered from inside the GFCI protected zone.  That should make your spider-sense tingle, hence, the conversation with the manufacturer.    Then you use one or both of the messengers to satisfy the requirement for the communication wire(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot Harper, that was a quick and very detailed response.

Is there a way to make this work without moving the 2-wire cables that go between the switches, the 2-wire cable that goes feeds the fan, and the 2-wire cable that goes between the top left regular outlet to the switch? Moving those would be a mess and would require tearing down walls and what not. Everything else I can move pretty much as I please, more or less.

​​​​​​​Thanks once again!

Comment: No.  Until 5 years ago when smart switches came out.  Then it's easy.  I'll write something up.

Comment: Worst case, I can tear down the wall and change the other cables too. I mean, if it's less fuss for you to help me on how to wire it all.

Thanks Harper!

Comment: @vladasonic updated with 2 options.  There are others but I don't like them.

Comment: Thanks Harper. Although I do indeed appreciate your help, this seems to complicated for me to understand without a drawing. And I definitely want to avoid the wireless stuff. Any way to do this without the lights and the fan being on the GFCI circuit?
Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: By "wireless stuff" do you mean any communicating smart switches or do you mean any wireless (radio) devices? Harper's option 2 is not wireless but it is a smart switch.

Comment: You will have to choose between installing communicating smart switches or replacing at least one cable.